# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $xf(y)-yf(x)=f\left( \frac yx\right)$

Tags: real-numbers, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy the following equation:
> $$xf(y)-yf(x)=f\left( \frac yx\right).$$

#### My work so far

1. If $x=1$ then $f(1)=0$
2. If $y=1$ then $f\left(\frac1x\right)=-f(x)$
3. If $y=\frac1x$ then $f\left(x^2\right)=\left(x+\frac1x\right)f(x)$

Comment: $y = 0$: $xf(0) = f(0) \implies f(0) = 0$.

Comment: What are the ranges of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I found two functions. (i) f(x)=0(trivial), (ii) f(x)=c(x-1/x), when x is not 0, f(0)=0. The first one is trivial case and I found the second function when I assume the differentiability of f.

Comment: @Servaes all functions f : Real numbers to Real numbers

Comment: By taking $y = -x \neq 0$, you find that $f(-x) + f(x) = f(-1)/x$. However, the left hand side is an even function, so the right side should be too. Thus $f(-1) = 0$ and, moreover, $f(x) = -f(-x)$ so $f$ is an odd function!

Comment: @EunsungLim Well apparently $x\neq0$ as otherwise $\tfrac{y}{x}$ doesn't make sense. Are there any other conditions on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Assuming $f(x)$ can be expressed as a Laurent series around $x=0$, then the function given by @EunsungLim is the only solution ($c = 0$ gives the zero function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient approach, but it works. I'll try to trim it down later.

You have already found that $f(x)=-f(\tfrac{1}{x})$, so then plugging in $x=-1$ shows that $f(-1)=0$. Next taking $y=-x$ in the original equation yields
$$xf(-x)+xf(x)=f(-1)=0,$$
which shows that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. It follows that for all nonzero $x\in\Bbb{R}$ we have
$$f(-\tfrac{1}{x})=f(x).$$
Now let $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ be nonzero. Then writing out the original equation for $-\tfrac{1}{x}$ and $-\tfrac{1}{y}$ yields
$$-\tfrac{1}{x}f(-\tfrac{1}{y})+\tfrac{1}{y}f(-\tfrac{1}{x})=f(\tfrac{x}{y})=-f(\tfrac{y}{x})=-xf(y)+yf(x).$$
But on the left hand side we can use the fact that $f(-\tfrac{1}{x})=f(x)$ to get
$$-\tfrac{1}{x}f(y)+\tfrac{1}{y}f(x)=-xf(y)+yf(x).$$
Rearranging terms shows that for all nonzero $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ with $x,y\neq\pm1$ we have
$$\frac{f(x)}{x-\tfrac{1}{x}}=\frac{f(y)}{y-\tfrac{1}{y}},$$
from which it follows that there is some constant $c\in\Bbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x)=c(x-\tfrac1x),$$
for all nonzero $x\in\Bbb{R}$, as we already saw that $f(\pm1)=0$.  Plugging in $y=0$ shows that also $f(0)=0$, and so every such function $f$ is (for some $c\in\Bbb{R}$) of the form
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0&\text{ if }x=0\\c(x-\tfrac{1}{x})&\text{ otherwise }\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$xf(y)-yf(x)=f\left( \frac yx\right) \\
\iff xf(y)-f(\frac{y}{x})-yf(x) = 0 \tag{1}$$

Substitute $x \to y/x$, $y \to y$:

$$\frac{y}{x}f(y) - yf( \frac{y}{x}) = f(x) \\
\iff \frac{y}{x}f(y) - yf( \frac{y}{x})-f(x) = 0 \tag{2}$$

Consider $(2)-(1)\times y$:

$$(\frac{y}{x}-xy)f(y)+(y^2-1)f(x)=0 \tag{3}$$

Let $y = 0$, As  M. Vinay said, $f(0) = 0$

$0\times f(0) + (0-1)f(x)=0 \implies f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

EDIT: My setting value is wrong(i.e. after formulate (3) , all what I did is wrong ) so I want to set them right.

Set $y = 0.5$ in (3), 
$$(\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{x}{2}) f(1/2) - 3/4 f(x) = 0 \\ \iff
f(x) =(\frac{2}{3x}-\frac{2x}{3}) f(1/2) $$

More precisely, $ f(x) = \frac{2}{3} f(1/2) \times(\frac{1}{x}-x)$

Let $\frac{2}{3} f(1/2) = c$ so$ f(x) = c(\frac{1}{x}-x)$

Since, c is an arbitrary constant, it includes my special solution $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: What about @EunsungLim's function $f(x) = c \left( x - \frac{1}{x} \right)$?

Comment: As @Eunsung Lim said $f(x)=c(x-1/x)$, when $x$ is not $0, f(0)=0.$

Comment: I can't find such function in my solution process maybe $f(0) \neq 0$ and let f(0) = c and hopefully get a perfecting answer.

Comment: But of course $ 0 \times u$ = 0, when $ u \in R$

Comment: There is a subtle problem in your answer, more precisely with the substitution you use. The initial equation is true for all $y$ and all $x \neq 0$. To make the substitution, it's better to have an intermediary variable $z = z(x,y) = y / x$; then $x = y / z$ and you get the equation $\frac{y}{z} f(y) - y f(y) = f(z)$, valable for all $y$ and all $x \neq 0$. Then you call $z = x$; but in the last equation, when you set $y = 0$, you need to recall $z = y/x$, and so $z = 0$ too...! This explains why you do not find the solutions of the type $x - 1/x$.

Comment: Let me rephrase, because I feel my previous comment is not very clear. The initial equation is true for all $x \neq 0$ and all $y$. When you set $z = y/x$ and express everything in terms of $y$ and $z$, you get an equation that is true for all values of $(y,z)$ that can be attained when $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \neq 0$; but for example $(y,z) = (0,1)$ is not one of these values, since $y = 0 \implies z = y/x = 0$ too.

Comment: Sorry for my naive and rude solution.