# Another FE, reduced it to $f(x)= - f( \frac 1x)$

Tags: functional-equations

Determine all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying: $$xf(y)-yf(x)=f(\frac yx)$$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}; x\neq 0$.

I found that $f(1)=0$ by plugging $x=y$. Another thing I found is that by putting $y=1$, we get the function $f(x)=-f(\frac 1x)$. Now I need help solving this function.

Comment: Does this mean that we can't solve for the original FE through this simplified version?

Comment: Seting $g(t)=f(e^t)$ gives $g(-t) = -g(t).$ Do you know the solutions to this FE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $xf(y)-yf(x)=f\left( \frac yx\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816896/find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-satisfying-xfy-yfx-f-left)