# Find the solution to $f(x)=-f(1/x)$.

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_{++}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be monotone increasing, concave and twice differentiable, such that $f(1)=0$.  What is the class of such $f$s that satisfy the property
$f(x)=-f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ ?

I know that, for example, the logarithm function does the job since it is increasing, concave, twice differentiable and $\log \left( x^{-1} \right)= - \log (x) $.

**EDIT**
Here is **an attempt**. Do you think it is correct?
By combining $f(1)=0$ with $f(x)=-f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ we have

$$f(x)+f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)=f(1)$$

so, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}_{++}$,

$$f(x)+f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)=f \left( x \cdot \frac{1}{x} \right)$$

Let $g(x)=f(e^{x})$, then

$$g\left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)= f \left( e^{x+ \frac{1}{x} } \right)=f \left( e^{x}  e^{\frac{1}{x}} \right) = f\left(  e^{x} \right) +  f\left(  e^{\frac{1}{x}} \right)= g(x) + g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
so that it must be
$$g\left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)= g\left( x \right) + g\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
This is an instance of the Cauchy functional equation whose only continuous solution is given by $g(x)=cx$ for some constant $c$.
The corresponding solution to my case is:
$$f(x)=c \log x$$

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: See a kind of generalization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816896/305862).

Answer (score 2):

Setting $x=e^t$, your functional equation becomes :

$$f(e^t)=-f(e^{-t})\tag{1}$$

Let $F=f \circ \exp$ ($\circ$ = function's composition).

(therefore $F$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$).

(1) becomes the equivalent functional equation

$$F(t)=-F(-t)\tag{2}$$

which amounts to say that $F$ is an odd function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Can you take it from here, taking into account the different constraints you have on $f$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Unfortunately I'm quite unexperienced with functional equation so I'm not sure how to procede from here. Given your answer I'm inclined to say that it must be $f(x)=F(\ln x)$ where F is increasing and odd, with $F(0)=0$. Since $\ln$ is concave, I can allow $F$ to be convex (provided $F''\leq F'$). Therefore any function of the sort $\alpha \ln x$ works but the family is much larger. Does it make sense? Again, thanks a lot for the suggestion.